# Explanation for very odd php function return

Tags: php, function

So my code in the past needed a variable to run through 2 functions and then return the value as such.

```
 function 1($variable) {
    check($variable);
    return $variable // either a -1, -2 or true;
 }

 // pass the return to next function

function 2($variable) {
    check($variable);
    return $variable // either a -1, -2 or true;
}
```

On the next check it returns a message to the user as such:

```
  if($variable == -1) // display message
  if($variable == -2) // display message
  if($variable == true) // display message
```

Now, per requirement of work the variable must go through a 3rd function check still returning a -1, -2 or true and then go onto the final if statements for display.
Now this is where it gets odd. If I keep it at 2 functions the if statements work, however if I run it through the 3rd check function I need to format my if's like this in order to correctly check the return:

```
if($variable === -1) // display message
if($variable === -2) // display message
if($variable === true) // display message
```

Notice I have to add the 3rd '=' symbol. I just can't figure out why this is happening. Is this normal by some PHP law I don't know about or is this a bug?

Comment: no bug, you want to comare type as well as value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not odd behavior, it's very natural for PHP.

Following expression:

```
if ($variable == true) {
}
```

means that PHP will cast left operand to less pretensive type(in this case BOOLEAN) and do comparison after this. Which obviously will result in TRUE if $variable value is not 0 or FALSE or NULL or ''

In second case i.e. === there is strict check value and type of both operands are compared.

Answer (score 1):

The triple equals sign (`===`) only returns `true` if the two objects being compared are *identical* (of the same type and value), not just equal.

For example:

```
$a = 1;
$b = "1";

echo $a == $b;  // True
echo $a === $b; // False
```

Comment: I understand that, but I don't get why PHP seems to be forcing me to use '==='. If I return -1 from the first, -1 from the second, -1 from the third, why doesn't this work in theory. if(-1 == -1)? It only works in this format if(-1 === -1); It's almost like PHP gets confused along the way and needs to make sure the values are of same type and value just to reassure itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show how you call the functions and store returns, there may be a problem. Plus, I suppose you called function 1 and 2 only for illustration because as you know you cant start name of the function with a number.

`===` is 'equals exactly' (value and type). Often used for logical tests, because sometimes you need to distinguish 0 from false and 1 from true.